# Android Gradle Dependency Duplicate Class Error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, transitive-dependency

After [installing Square's Reader SDK](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/reader-sdk/build-on-android#step-3-configure-the-build-dependencies) into my app, I'm running into duplicate class errors between some Gradle dependencies as shown below.

- My app module dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  def readerSdkVersion = "1.3.5"
  implementation "com.squareup.sdk.reader:reader-sdk-$SQUARE_READER_SDK_APPLICATION_ID:$readerSdkVersion"
  runtimeOnly ("com.squareup.sdk.reader:reader-sdk-internals:$readerSdkVersion") {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.phrase', module: 'phrase'
  }
  implementation 'com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0'

  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

- ... and the build failure I get even though I tried excluding the conflicting group/module from [Square's Phrase dependency](https://github.com/square/phrase):

```
Duplicate class com.squareup.phrase.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-phrase-1.1.0.jar (com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0) and reader-sdk-internals-1.3.5.jar (com.squareup.sdk.reader:reader-sdk-internals:1.3.5)
Duplicate class com.squareup.phrase.ListPhrase found in modules jetified-phrase-1.1.0.jar (com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0) and reader-sdk-internals-1.3.5.jar (com.squareup.sdk.reader:reader-sdk-internals:1.3.5)
Duplicate class com.squareup.phrase.ListPhrase$1 found in modules jetified-phrase-1.1.0.jar (com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0) and reader-sdk-internals-1.3.5.jar (com.squareup.sdk.reader:reader-sdk-internals:1.3.5)
Duplicate class com.squareup.phrase.ListPhrase$Formatter found in modules jetified-phrase-1.1.0.jar (com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0) and reader-sdk-internals-1.3.5.jar (com.squareup.sdk.reader:reader-sdk-internals:1.3.5)
Duplicate class com.squareup.phrase.Phrase found in modules jetified-phrase-1.1.0.jar (com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0) and reader-sdk-internals-1.3.5.jar (com.squareup.sdk.reader:reader-sdk-internals:1.3.5)
Duplicate class com.squareup.phrase.Phrase$KeyToken found in modules jetified-phrase-1.1.0.jar (com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0) and reader-sdk-internals-1.3.5.jar (com.squareup.sdk.reader:reader-sdk-internals:1.3.5)
Duplicate class com.squareup.phrase.Phrase$LeftCurlyBracketToken found in modules jetified-phrase-1.1.0.jar (com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0) and reader-sdk-internals-1.3.5.jar (com.squareup.sdk.reader:reader-sdk-internals:1.3.5)
Duplicate class com.squareup.phrase.Phrase$TextToken found in modules jetified-phrase-1.1.0.jar (com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0) and reader-sdk-internals-1.3.5.jar (com.squareup.sdk.reader:reader-sdk-internals:1.3.5)
Duplicate class com.squareup.phrase.Phrase$Token found in modules jetified-phrase-1.1.0.jar (com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.1.0) and reader-sdk-internals-1.3.5.jar (com.squareup.sdk.reader:reader-sdk-internals:1.3.5)
```

Am I missing something here? And yes, I have all of the other Gradle configurations (i.e. multidex and compile options set) as mentioned in the SDK's docs mentioned earlier.